# Remove all chars that are not a digit from a string

Tags: bash, grep

I'm trying to make a small function that removes all the chars that are not digits.

> 123a45a ---> will become ---> 12345

I've came up with :

```
temp=$word | grep -o [[:digit:]]
echo $temp
```

But instead of `12345` I get `1 2 3 4 5`. How to I get rid of the spaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using `sed`?

```
$ echo "123a45a" | sed -r 's/[^0-9]//g'
12345
```

As I read you are just allowed to use `grep` and `tr`, this can make the trick:

```
$ echo "123a45a" | grep -o [[:digit:]] | tr -d '\n'
12345
```

In your case,

```
temp=$(echo $word | grep -o [[:digit:]] | tr -d '\n')
```

Comment: Thanks, last one is doing the job great =]

Comment: See my answer for a better way with `tr`. :-)

Comment: This is a [Useless Use of Echo](http://fahdshariff.blogspot.com/2012/12/useless-use-of-echo.html). Use `temp=$(grep -o [[:digit:]] <<< "$word"| tr -d '\n')` instead.

Answer (score 8):

Pure bash:

```
word=123a45a 
number=${word//[^0-9]}
```

Answer (score 6):

Here's a pure bash solution

```
var='123a45a'
echo ${var//[^0-9]/}
12345
```

Answer (score 4):

is this what you are looking for?

```
kent$  echo "123a45a"|sed 's/[^0-9]//g'
12345
```

**grep & tr**

```
echo "123a45a"|grep -o '[0-9]'|tr -d '\n'
12345
```

Comment: @NadavPeled strange requirement... homework? there are some other bash parameter expansion answers, are they allowed?

Comment: Yep :\ homework.. part of a small project..
In this section we are only allowed to use grep\tr

Comment: @NadavPeled ok, `tr` is allowed. then it is ok. I added in answer. but others have already posted the similar.

Comment: Yea, many thanks :] had to give the green mark to the first who posted it, doing the job really very good.

Comment: @Kent: See my answer for a better `tr` approach. :-)

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using `sed` or `perl` instead:

```
temp="$(sed -e 's/[^0-9]//g' <<< "$word")"
temp="$(perl -pe 's/\D//g' <<< "$word")"
```

---

**Edited to add:** If you really need to use `grep`, then this is the only way I can think of:

```
temp="$( grep -o '[0-9]' <<< "$word" \
         | while IFS= read -r ; do echo -n "$REPLY" ; done
       )"
```

. . . but there's probably a better way. (It uses `grep -o`, like your solution, then runs over the lines that it outputs and re-outputs them without line-breaks.)

---

**Edited again to add:** Now that you've mentioned that you use can use `tr` instead, this is much easier:

```
temp="$(tr -cd 0-9 <<< "$word")"
```

Comment: +1 for `tr`. clean & simple. & this question's use case is exactly what `tr` is for.

Answer (score 2):

tr will also work:

```
echo "123a45a" | tr -cd '[:digit:]'

# output: 12345
```

Comment: "remove all the chars that are not digits" `echo '123!@#45abc' | tr -d '[:alpha:]'`

Comment: Now this is a sub-answer of ruakh's answer, but nevermind (-1 -> +1) :-)

Comment: @anishsane: True and not taking any credit away from rukah but this was the first `tr` based answer but thanks to you it needed to be fine tuned further :P

Answer (score 0):

`Grep` returns the result on different lines:

```
$ echo -e "$temp"
1
2
3
4
5
```

So you cannot remove those spaces during the filtering, but you can afterwards, since `$temp` can transform itself like this:

```
temp=`echo $temp | tr -d ' '`
$ echo "$temp"
12345
```